# Joomla, Zoo, Category renderer

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, cck

I am trying to find where I can customise the view of automatically generated Joomla Zoo categories.

Someone has created a new application within the Zoo called Human Resources.
It has a category structure setup as per:

```
Category 1
   Sub Category 1
   Sub Category 2
   Sub Category 3
Category 2
   Sub Category 1
   Sub Category 2
   Sub Category 3
Category 3
   ...
```

Etc...

Once you get through to an item (i.e. clicking on an item from a sub category page I can edit the layout within full.php.

Category 1 for instance seems to be mapped to teaser.php and I can modify the layout here too.

However category 2 and the sub categories of category 2 render, but I can't for the life of me find what renderer they are using.

I have gone through all the files int he application asking them to die(); to no avail.

Any help as to how I can find out how and where these category pages are being rendered would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,

Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Try these few sample steps to create the category and sub-category menu Items through Joomla admin control panel.

```
1)Create a new Menu in the Menu Manager called "Pets".
2)Add a new Menu Item called "Dogs". For this example, we don't really care what the type of the Menu Items is. For example, you can just create one article called "Pet Menu Test" and then create all of the Menu Items as type Article → Article Layout and point to this article.
3)Add a second Menu Item called "Collies" (again, Menu Type of Article Layout as above). In the Parent Item box, select "Dogs", as shown below:
4)Add a third Menu Item called "Greyhounds", again making "Dogs" the Parent Item. (Remember, these can all point to the same article.)
5)Add the "Cats" Menu Item. Be sure to make the Parent Item for this "Top".
6)Add the last two Menu Items, "Tabbies" and "Siamese", making "Cats" the Parent Item for both.
```

try to get more details here,

```
https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_submenu
```